# Single word for "always new requirements"

Tags: single-word-requests, formality

Is there any word to express "always new needs emerge"? Can *renewable* be sufficient for this? The context is something like "cannot satisfy the endless renewable needs", in an academic article.

Comment: No. Look up *renewable* in a dictionary. You will have to also look up a thesaurus to find a suitable word or phrase to mean "endlessly repeating/ recurring" such as **perpetual**.

Comment: If I understood the context correctly, I would suggest "ever changing". It's not a single word, but can be useful at times: "cannot satisfy the ever changing needs..."

Comment: Depending on the exact context, the phrase "moving target" can express this idea. And something like "endlessly shifting [goalposts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_the_goalposts#Feature_creep)" would work in the example you give.

Comment: If it is something like "an idea or situation that continuously changes as you are trying to deal with it", you have a [*moving target.*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/target)

Comment: @JLG It's about something come with new needs after every time you satisfy its needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider describing them as ***evolving*** needs.

The idea of ongoing change is embedded in the word *evolving*, and the phrase already has [some currency](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22evolving%20needs%22&oq=%22evolving%20needs%22).